# Rewrite Rule for redirection?

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

How to write Apache Rewrite Rule ?
I want to redirect http://abc.com/test/filename.air to http://abc.com/test/filename.exe .

I tried

```
ProxyPass /test/filename.air http://abc.com/test/filename.exe
```

And

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/filename.air $1/filename.exe
```

Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

> RedirectMatch (.*)/filename.air$ $1/filename.exe